# Yii copying data from one model to another

Tags: yii

I'm new to yii. I collect data from a form using a model extended by `CFormModel` and inside controller I want to copy these data to a model which is extended from `CActiveRecord` in order to save to DB. Is there a method or way to copy data from data collected model to data saving model rather than doing this by attribute to attribute as it's so ugly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can get all models attributes by:

```
$data = $model->attributes;
```

and assign them to another model

```
$anotherModel = new AnotherActiveRecord();
$anotherModel->setAttributes($data);
$anotherModel->save();
```

now another model will extract whatever it can from `$data`

Comment: In later versions of Laravel, this should be `$data = $model->attributesToArray();` and `$anotherModel->setRawAttributes($data);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following method

```
public function cloneModel($className,$model) {
    $attributes = $model->attributes;
    $newObj = new $className;
    foreach($attributes as  $attribute => $val) {
        $newObj->{$attribute} = $val;
    }
    return $newObj;
}
```

Define this in dome component , say UtilityComponent.
Then you can call as

```
$modelTemp = $new ModelClass();
$model->someAttr = 'someVal';
$clonedModel = Yii::$app->utilities->cloneModel(ModelClass::class,$modelTemp);
```